# How to get rid of annotations on faceted graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, annotate, ggpubr

### Problem

I am trying to label the left facet side of my graph while leaving out the annotations on the right side.

### Data

Here are my libraries and data:

```
#### Libraries ####

library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(plotly)

#### Dput ####
emlit <- structure(list(X = 1:20, Ethnicity = c("Asian (other than Chinese)", 
                                                "Filipino", "Indonesian", "Thai", "Japanese", "Korean", "South Asian", 
                                                "Indian", "Nepalese", "Pakistani", "Other South Asian", "Other Asian", 
                                                "White", "Mixed", "With Chinese parent", "Other mixed", "Others", 
                                                "All ethnic minorities", "All ethnic minorities,  excluding\n    foreign domestic helpers", 
                                                "Whole population"), Age_5.14 = c(65.8, 72.2, 69.4, 83.1, 26.6, 
                                                                                  52.4, 67.4, 60.4, 69.5, 71.5, 92.5, 92, 34.8, 76.6, 84.2, 45.3, 
                                                                                  51.3, 64.3, 64.3, 94.8), Age_15.24 = c(28.1, 29.2, 4.4, 72.9, 
                                                                                                                         34.8, 50.3, 38.7, 41.4, 22.2, 54.3, 41.9, 64.7, 24.4, 82.9, 90.7, 
                                                                                                                         37.4, 53.2, 40.6, 52.9, 96.9), Age_25.34 = c(4.5, 1.8, 4.6, 20, 
                                                                                                                                                                      17.2, 26.8, 6.6, 4.2, 6.4, 11.9, 12, 33.9, 15, 60.5, 82, 6.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                      11.2, 7.8, 21.8, 84.9), Age_35.44 = c(6.3, 2, 6.1, 35.7, 36.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            25.5, 9.4, 6.2, 10.5, 10.1, 22.4, 35.7, 8.6, 63, 83.2, 4.5, 12.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            9.5, 23.4, 84.6), Age_45.54 = c(8.1, 2.3, 8, 23.2, 43.4, 59.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            7.5, 6.3, 3.9, 13.5, 28.3, 47.5, 13.1, 72.1, 84, 4.4, 22.4, 14.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            27.7, 92.5), Age_55.64 = c(15.9, 4.4, 44, 27, 41.7, 52.8, 11.8, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       7.4, 9.5, 2, 54.2, 39.6, 12.7, 75.3, 80.1, 2.6, 20.6, 25, 32.4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       94.8), Age_65. = c(31.1, 11.9, 82.6, 39, 46.4, 57, 9.5, 3.9, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          NA, 11.4, 66.5, 74.5, 14.5, 80.5, 81, 57.5, 13.6, 42.7, 44, 82.3
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ), Age_Overall = c(10.1, 3.5, 6.4, 31.4, 35.1, 39.8, 20.4, 15.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          16.4, 33.8, 30.4, 46.3, 15.4, 72.7, 83.9, 19.4, 19.8, 16.9, 35.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          89.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I have also pivoted the data for my graph:

```
#### Pivot Data ####
emlitpivot <- emlit %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("Age"),
               names_to = "Age_Range",
               values_to = "Percent")
```

### Plot

Here is my plot so far, a faceted graph that breaks down literacy by age with some notes on some important points on the left:

```
#### EM vs all ####

# Order
order <- c("5-14", "15-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65+", "Overall",
           "5-14", "15-24", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65+", "Overall")

# Plot
plot <- emlitpivot %>% 
  filter(Ethnicity %in% c("All ethnic minorities",
                          "Whole population")) %>% 
  ggbarplot(x="Age_Range",
            y="Percent",
            fill = "Ethnicity",
            label = T,
            palette = "jco",
            facet.by = "Ethnicity",
            title = "EM x Native Chinese Literacy by Age",
            xlab = "Age Range",
            ylab = "Literacy in Chinese (By Percent)",
            caption = "*Data obtained from Census and Statistics Department Hong Kong SAR, 2016.")+
  theme_cleveland()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                                   hjust = .5,
                                   vjust = .5),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic"))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=order)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 3, y = 15, xend = 3, yend = 48))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 71, xend = 1, yend = 80))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 7, y = 50, xend = 7, yend = 65))+
  annotate("text",
           x=4,
           y=53,
           label = "Post-college workers can't read.")+
  annotate("text",
           x=3.5,
           y=85,
           label = "School age supports seem to boost initial literacy.")+
  annotate("text",
           x=6,
           y=70,
           label = "Increase due to generational literacy?")

# Print plot:
plot
```

However, you can probably guess what the problem is:

[image]

How do I get rid of the annotations on the right? I'm not sure if there is a simple way of getting rid of them, but it would be helpful to only have text on the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I'll use `geom_text` instead of `annotate`, since it allows you to have `subset` of your data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

emlitpivot %>%
  filter(Ethnicity %in% c(
    "All ethnic minorities",
    "Whole population"
  )) %>%
  ggbarplot(
    x = "Age_Range",
    y = "Percent",
    fill = "Ethnicity",
    label = T,
    palette = "jco",
    facet.by = "Ethnicity",
    title = "EM x Native Chinese Literacy by Age",
    xlab = "Age Range",
    ylab = "Literacy in Chinese (By Percent)",
    caption = "*Data obtained from Census and Statistics Department Hong Kong SAR, 2016."
  ) +
  theme_cleveland() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      angle = 45,
      hjust = .5,
      vjust = .5
    ),
    legend.position = "none",
    plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic")
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = order) +
  geom_segment(data = subset(emlitpivot, Ethnicity == "All ethnic minorities"), aes(x = 3, y = 15, xend = 3, yend = 48)) +
  geom_segment(data = subset(emlitpivot, Ethnicity == "All ethnic minorities"), aes(x = 1, y = 71, xend = 1, yend = 80)) +
  geom_segment(data = subset(emlitpivot, Ethnicity == "All ethnic minorities"), aes(x = 7, y = 50, xend = 7, yend = 65)) +
  geom_text(data = subset(emlitpivot, Ethnicity == "All ethnic minorities"), aes(4, 53), label = "Post-college workers can't read.", check_overlap = T) +
  geom_text(data = subset(emlitpivot, Ethnicity == "All ethnic minorities"), aes(3.5, 85), label = "School age supports seem to boost initial literacy.", check_overlap = T) +
  geom_text(data = subset(emlitpivot, Ethnicity == "All ethnic minorities"), aes(6, 70), label = "Increase due to generational literacy?", check_overlap = T)
```

[image: ggbarplot_geom_text_order]

Comment: Is there a way to get the x axis to include the age ranges I had originally?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to load your `order` vector, if you run the code yourself, you should see the correct x axis with orders in `order`, updated my graph

Answer (score 1):

**Update remove lines in second facet:**

Create a dataframe with your text labels and position and add it to the plot,
to remove the lines do the same procedure:

df for text = ann_text
df for lines = segm

```
ann_text <- data.frame(x = c(4, 3.5, 6),
                       y = c(53, 85, 70),
                       lab = c("Post-college workers can't read.", "School age supports seem to boost initial literacy.",
                               "Increase due to generational literacy?"),
                       Ethnicity = rep("All ethnic minorities", 3))
segm <- data.frame(x = c(3,1,7),
                   y = c(15, 71, 50),
                   xend = c(3,1,7),
                   yend = c(48,80,65),
                   Ethnicity = rep("All ethnic minorities", 3))
plot1 <- plot +
  geom_text(
    data    = ann_text,
    mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = lab)
  )
plot1 + geom_segment(
    data = segm,
    mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)
    )
```

remove the following from your code:

```
 annotate("text",
           x=4,
           y=53,
           label = "Post-college workers can't read.")+
  annotate("text",
           x=3.5,
           y=85,
           label = "School age supports seem to boost initial literacy.")+
  annotate("text",
           x=6,
           y=70,
           label = "Increase due to generational literacy?")
```

[image]

Comment: What about the lines on the right graph? How would you get rid of them in this case?

Comment: Ok will solve it!

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: I got it to work. I prefer the more parsimonious version above but I've upvoted your answer since its still useful to know :)